# How do you get the equation of polynomial regression using ggplot and R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot some data and add a third order polynomial trend line. I'm using the lm() and coef() functions to obtain a model for my data and then plot with ggplot.

Here is the relevant code:

`Bytes` is the name of my dependent variable (y). `Resolution` is the name of my independent variable (x).

```
model = lm(Bytes~poly(Resolution, 3), averaged_frame)
print(coef(model))

library(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(averaged_frame, mapping = aes(x = Resolution, y = Bytes)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="lm", formula = y~poly(x, 3), se = FALSE)
```

However, when I take the coefficients from `print(coef(model))`:

```
         (Intercept) poly(Resolution, 3)1 poly(Resolution, 3)2 poly(Resolution, 3)3 
           0.3392046            0.3686154            0.2504288            0.1274490
```

And transpose them into a function:

```
f(x)=0.1274490x^3+0.2504288x^2+0.3686154x+0.3392046
```

And graph it, it looks completely different to the plot on ggplot.

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong here or how I might get an equation from the line in ggplot.

Comment: You should use `raw = TRUE` in `poly`. That's why you get a different curve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the **ggpmisc** package. This is for an order one regression, you have to adapt to your case.

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 20 + 30 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 80)

library(ggpmisc)

my_formula <- y ~ x

myformat <- "y = %s + %s x --- R²: %s"
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = my_formula, se = FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    formula = my_formula, output.type = "numeric",
    mapping = aes(
      label = 
        sprintf(
          myformat,
          formatC(after_stat(coef.ls)[[1]][[1, "Estimate"]]),
          formatC(after_stat(coef.ls)[[1]][[2, "Estimate"]]),
          formatC(stat(r.squared))),
    ),
    vstep = 0.1,
    size = 10
  )
```

[image]